# Ethereum smartcontract automatical transactions - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, php, ethereum, smartcontracts

I've just made a smartcontract for an ICO, and now i need to implement the following functionality:

1.User sent amount of ETH to the wallet

2.User gets some amount of tokens to his wallet in exchange for sent ETH automatically

Im pretty new to all of this, so i want to know - is it even possible to do this **automatically** (or only in manual mode?), if not with smartcontract itself, maybe there is another way to do that, like getting events and calling functions from a smartcontract with some kind of API from, for example, PHP or JS?
If it's possible when can i find some info about this?
Found only several questions like this one, but no answers.

Here is the contract code (taken mostly from [here](https://www.ethereum.org/token#full-coin-code)):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract owned {
  address public owner;

  function owned() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier onlyOwner {
    if (msg.sender != owner) return;
    _;
  }

  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
    owner = newOwner;
  }
}

contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 
_value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }

contract token {
/* Public variables of the token */
string public standard = 'Token 0.1';
string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 public decimals;
uint256 public totalSupply;

/* This creates an array with all balances */
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

/* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients 
*/
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

/* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the 
contract */
function token(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    uint8 decimalUnits,
    string tokenSymbol
    ) {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator 
    all initial tokens
    totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total 
    supply
    name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for 
    display purposes
    symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol 
    for display purposes
    decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of 
    decimals for display purposes
}

/* Send coins */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) return;           // Check if the 
sender has enough
    if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) return; // Check for 
overflows
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from 
the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to 
the recipient
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone 
listening that this transfer took place
}

/* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
    returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    return true;
}

/* Approve and then communicate the approved contract in a single tx */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
    returns (bool success) {    
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }
}

/* A contract attempts to get the coins */
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns 
(bool success) {
    if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) return;                 // Check if the 
 sender has enough
    if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) return;  // Check for 
 overflows
    if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) return;   // Check allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from 
 the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to 
 the recipient
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/* This unnamed function is called whenever someone tries to send ether to 
it */
function () {
    return;     // Prevents accidental sending of ether
}
}

contract MyAdvancedToken is owned, token {

uint256 public sellPrice;
uint256 public buyPrice;

mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

/* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients 
*/
 event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

 /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the 
 contract */
function MyAdvancedToken(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    uint8 decimalUnits,
    string tokenSymbol
) token (initialSupply, tokenName, decimalUnits, tokenSymbol) {}

/* Send coins */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) return;           // Check if the 
sender has enough
    if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) return; // Check for 
overflows
    if (frozenAccount[msg.sender]) return;                // Check if frozen
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from 
the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to 
the recipient
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone 
listening that this transfer took place
}


/* A contract attempts to get the coins */
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns 
(bool success) {
    if (frozenAccount[_from]) return;                        // Check if 
frozen            
    if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) return;                 // Check if the 
sender has enough
    if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) return;  // Check for 
overflows
    if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) return;   // Check allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from 
the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to 
the recipient
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner {
    balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
    totalSupply += mintedAmount;
    Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
    Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
}

function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner {
    frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
    FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
}

function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner {
    sellPrice = newSellPrice;
    buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
}

function buy() payable {
    uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                // calculates the 
amount
    if (balanceOf[this] < amount) return;               // checks if it has 
enough to sell
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;                   // adds the amount to 
buyer's balance
    balanceOf[this] -= amount;                         // subtracts amount 
from seller's balance
    Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);                // execute an event 
reflecting the change
}

function sell(uint256 amount) {
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < amount ) return;        // checks if the 
sender has enough to sell
    balanceOf[this] += amount;                         // adds the amount to 
owner's balance
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;                   // subtracts the 
amount from seller's balance
    if (!msg.sender.send(amount * sellPrice)) {        // sends ether to the 
seller. It's important
        return;                                         // to do this last 
to avoid recursion attacks
    } else {
        Transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);            // executes an event 
reflecting on the change
    }               
}
}
```

Excuse me for my possible stupidity and bad english:)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I didn't understand what do you mean by `automatically`. But I think that you want to send the tokens for everyone who sends ETH to your contract without need to call `buy` method. At least that is what I did for [Jincor Pre ICO](https://ico.jincor.com/) and you can check the code on [Github](https://github.com/JincorTech/ico/blob/master/contracts/JincorTokenPreSale.sol)
You can achieve that by adding to your contract `MyAdvancedToken`:
```

```
 function () payable {
        buy();
    }
```

```
Sorry if I didn't get your message well.

Answer (score -1):

when ether come to contract address function

```
function() payable {..}
```

called.

You can define this function in contract and use [globally available variables](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties):
msg.value - amount of ether (number of wei)
msg.sender  - addres who send ether